# How to define global path for all requests in a scenario

Tags: karate

In the example below I'm trying to define a path in the background for all requests in the feature file.  I'm not sure why it works for the first request in the first scenario and the second scenario but not for the second request in the first scenario.  In my real test for the first scenario, I get an item first, delete it and then verify that it is gone.  The path is the same in all requests.

```
Background:  
  * configure headers = { 'Authorization': '#(token)' }  
  * url baseUrl  
  * path 'items'  

Scenario: Get item 1 and 2  
  Given path '1'  
  When method get  
  Then status 200  

  Given path '2'  
  When method get  
  Then status 200  

Scenario: Get item 3  
  Given path '3'  
  When method get  
  Then status 200
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `url` for getting the 'global' effect, not path. Try this:

```
Background:  
  * configure headers = { 'Authorization': '#(token)' }  
  * url baseUrl + '/items'
```

Refer to the documentation for `path`: https://github.com/intuit/karate#url